# How choose cmake external project target

Tags: cmake

I am writing a `cmake` file for a personal project and I would to choose the target I want to build when I use `ExternalProject_Add`. Is it Possible and how ?

After that lets suppose that the exetrnals target I want to compile are target1 and target2. How can I do something like 
`target_link_libraries(mytarget target1 target 2)` ?

I don't want to use a path like `somepath/libtarget1.a` because It wouldnt be portable at all.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: "I don't want to use a path like `somepath/libtarget1.a` because It wouldnt be portable at all." - Then you should have external project **already installed** when you configure yours one, and use `find_package()` for get project's targets. Or include external project via `add_subdirectory`. Whenever external project is based on CMake or not, its targets are not seen by the caller of `ExternalProject_Add`.

Comment: Thank you, I had a misunderstanding on what ExternalProject_Add is. I will use add_subdirectories